# Error deploying Hackernews Vue 2.0 sample code to Heroku and Google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, heroku, vue.js

I am new to JS/Node.js/Vue.js and trying to learn about it and deploy the Hackernews code at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0. I was successfully able to deploy it locally on Windows 10 and Ubuntu and it worked fine (node v8.1.2, npm 5.0.3). After that, I tried deploying it on Heroku (`git push heroku master`) and also Google Could AppEngine (`gcloud app deploy app.yaml`) and I got the error "Cannot find module ./dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json" with both. Details below:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
yarn start v0.27.5
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:41:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

While trying to debug this issue further, I changed the `package.json` (line 8) from:
`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",`
to:
`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",`

and that also works fine locally. But on Heroku and Google cloud deployment, I got the different error:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
yarn start v0.27.5
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/webpack.client.config.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I checked that the 'glob' dependency is there in package.json. Is this an issue with the code or am I missing something in my environment to deploy this to the cloud? What are the options to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: i am getting same error here. have you found solution for it ?

Comment: I was missing some steps from [https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0]: 
`
    # install dependencies
    npm install # or yarn

    # serve in dev mode, with hot reload at localhost:8080
    npm run dev

    # build for production
    npm run build

    # serve in production mode
    npm start

Comment: thank you. also i am facing problem implementing authentication for this kind of project. do you have any suggestion on how to implement authentication for server side rendered app with vue.js and vuex ?